# Python - Compare Tuples in a List

Tags: list, python-3.x, tuples

So in a program I am creating I have a list that contains tuples, and each tuple contains 3 numbers. For example...

```
my_list = [(1, 2, 4), (2, 4, 1), (1, 5, 2), (1, 4, 1),...]
```

Now I want to delete any tuple whose last two numbers are less than any other tuple's last two numbers are.

- The first number has to be the same to delete the tuple. *

So with the list of tuples above this would happen...

```
my_list = [(1, 2, 4), (2, 4, 1), (1, 5, 2), (1, 4, 1),...]
# some code...
result = [(1, 2, 4), (2, 4, 1), (1, 5, 2)]
```

The first tuple is not deleted because (2 and 4) are not less than (4 and 1 -> 2 < 4 but 4 > 1), (1 and 5 -> 2 > 1), or (4 and 1 -> 2 < 4 but 4 > 1)

The second tuple is not deleted because its first number (2) is different than every other tuples first number.

The third tuple is not deleted for the same reason the first tuple is not deleted.

The fourth tuple is deleted because (4 and 1) is less than (5 and 2 -> 4 < 5 and 1 < 2)

I really need help because I am stuck in my program and I have no idea what to do. I'm not asking for a solution, but just some guidance as to how to even begin solving this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I think this might actually work. I just figured it out. Is this the best solution?

```
results = [(1, 2, 4), (2, 4, 1), (1, 5, 2), (1, 4, 1)]
for position in results:
    for check in results:
        if position[0] == check[0] and position[1] < check[1] and position[2] < check[2]:
            results.remove(position)
```

Comment: Never, ever modify structures as you iterate over them. Iterate over a copy.

Comment: In theory, this would work except for what Coldspeed mentioned. Do not ever modify the iterator as you iterate over it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple list comprehension to do this:

```
[i for i in l if not any([i[0]==j[0] and i[1]<j[1] and i[2]<j[2] for j in my_list])]
```

Your loop would work too, but be sure not to modify the list as you are iterating over it.

```
my_list = [(1, 2, 4), (2, 4, 1), (1, 5, 2), (1, 4, 1)]
results = []
for position in my_list:
    for check in my_list:
        if not (position[0] == check[0] and position[1] < check[1] and position[2] < check[2]):
            results.append(position)

results
>[(1, 2, 4), (2, 4, 1), (1, 5, 2)]
```